# Redisson RMAP Write Through Caching

Tags: redisson

I'm running the Sample Code from Redisson. I notice the RMAP Write Through will write to the cache before running the MapWriter method. Since it is synchronous, I would like to update the database first, and then the Redis cache if the query/transaction is successful. I am throwing errors in the method but cache still has the data as if error never occurred. Using the Write Though MapOption.

https://github.com/redisson/redisson-examples/blob/master/collections-examples/src/main/java/org/redisson/example/collections/MapReadWriteThroughExamples.java

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: What is the data in cache in this case? since error returned instead of data

Comment: Thanks for the assist! 

I'm using the posted code right from the GitHub. 

I'm running the first test successfully with local MySQL and local Redis. 

When I run it again, I get a duplicate key error from MySQL, which I can work around. However, if I write "Willy2" in my second run, the database will not be updated and show "Willy", and the cache Hashmap "myMap" will show "Willy2" 

So it is out of sync, even though the Redis exception was thrown. I assumed the RedisException would stop the cache from writing. I am using the WriteThrough strategy. Appreciate your help!